# RecyclerView Get view at particular position and retrieve data from it android kotlin

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview

i have recyclerview item which has 4 edittexts. Also i have add new item button which add new item and new edittexts(they need to be populated from the use) i`m trying to retrieve all data from the fields when user click save button. Here is my code:

```
class SectionsRecyclerAdapter(private val educationList: MutableList<Any>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<SectionsRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    class ViewHolder(val item: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(item)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_new_section, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = educationList.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if (holder != null) {
            holder.item.deleteBtn.visibility = if (position != 0) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE

            holder.item.deleteBtn.setOnClickListener {
                educationList.removeAt(position)
                notifyItemRemoved(position)
                notifyItemRangeRemoved(position, educationList.size)
            }
        }
    }

    fun addItem() {
        educationList.add(EducationModel())
        notifyItemInserted(educationList.size)
    }
}
```

**Education Fragment :**

```
class EducationFragment : Fragment(), ValidationInterface {

private var educationList: MutableList<Any> = mutableListOf()
private lateinit var sectionAdapter : SectionsRecyclerAdapter

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_education, container, false)
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    educationList.add(EducationModel())

    sectionAdapter = SectionsRecyclerAdapter(educationList)

    educationRv.apply {
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        adapter = ScaleInAnimationAdapter(sectionAdapter)
        itemAnimator = LandingAnimator()
    }

    addSectionBtn.setOnClickListener {
        sectionAdapter.addItem()
        educationRv.smoothScrollToPosition(educationList.size)
    }
}

companion object {
    val instance = EducationFragment()
}

override fun validateAndSave(): Boolean {

    //Here i want to get data from every child and then parse it to my model EducationModel
    val model = educationRv.getChildAt(0)
    list.add(model)
    CreateResumeActivity.modelInstance.educationList.addAll(list)

    return true
}
```

Of course if there are better solution i will be glad, but for now i`m stuck with this... My main goal is when user click save i need to retrieve value from the edittext ( University, StartDate, EndDate, Summary) and put it in EducationModels

Answer (score 0):

Inside a recycler view each view holder can recycle his views. For that reason you have to keep all edittext values in a public list inside your adapter and access it from component which hold that adapter. Here is an proof of concept:

```
class MyAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter(private val educationList: MutableList<Any>) {
    val holderList = educationList.map { EditTextValues(...) };
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        //fill edit text just in case that it is recycled
        holder.editText.text = holderList[position].editTextValue
        holder.editText.onTextChangeLister { holderList[position] = EditTextValues(holder.editText.text) }
    }
}

class MyAndroidComponent : Fragment {
     val adapter: MyAdapter = ...
     fun onCreate() {
          saveButton.setOnClickListener {
               // you can access your edit texts values here
               adapter.holderList
          }
     }
}
```